# Difference between distance and activation network into accord.net

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, neural-network, accord.net

Сould you explain the significant difference between distance and activation network into Accord.NET? In which cases is it best to use them?

DN: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Neuro_DistanceNetwork.htm
AN: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Neuro_ActivationNetwork.htm

Comment: It may make sense to provide some links to the two items (maybe their help docs) to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: It's too broad question for this site unfortunately. You can read documentation links you provided more carefully. For example, first states at the bottom: "The network is a base for such neural networks as SOM, Elastic net, et". Then you can google for what SOM is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map. And so on.